# How to add symbols in a form field?

Tags: jsp, textbox, xhtml

My form has a textbox to input a 9 digit number. Once the user enters the digits, i wish to format the text box in the following way :

123456789 gets altered to 12-345-6789

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple if you can use Java script. This code uses plain Javascript (just add it to your page).

```
<script>
function formatText(){
var text = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
var fmtTxt = text.substr(0,2)+"-"+text.substr(2,3)+"-"+text.substr(5,4);
document.getElementById("txt1").value = fmtTxt;
}
</script>
```

You still need to add the formatText method to the onchange event belonging to your text field element.

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" onchange="formatText()">
```